# Generate A Chart Using Javascript in Mediawiki Extension

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm currently trying to generate a chart using javascript in a MediaWiki extension after loading the data with the same extension from a MySQL database. The chart uses the Chart.js library for displaying the data.

The chart is not showing up and I believe it is because MediaWiki does not support running javascript after a page has been loaded in an attempt to prevent wiki users from writing javascript functions into the page.

Does anyone know of a way around this safeguard? The extension uses a form to get info about what data will be displayed in this chart so it has to be dynamically created (which I am doing through generating the HTML and javascript via PHP functions).

Comment: There is no such safeguard. Chances are your script is running later or earlier than expected (e.g. before the article content has been loaded) and doing nothing as a result.